# sqlite DB does not work

Tags: java, android, sqlite, import

i need a working database with following data, and i should be able to get data from it, by pushing button, please help

here is code

```
package com.example.prog;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Locale;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button Button1;
    Button Button2;
    Button Button3;
    Button Button4;
    Button Button5;
    Button Button6;
    Button Button7;
    Button Button8;
    Button Button9;
    Button Button10;

    TextView textView1;
    TextView textView2;
    TextView textView3;

    TextView textView4;
    TextView textView5;
    TextView textView6;
    TextView textView7;
    TextView textView8;
    TextView textView9;
    TextView textView10;
    TextView textView11;

    EditText editText1;
    EditText editText2;
    EditText editText3;
    EditText editText7;
    EditText editText5;

    final int MENU_main_Q = 0;
    final int MENU_main_Q_1 = 7;
    final int MENU_main_Q_2 = 8;
    final int MENU_main_Q_3 = 9;

    final int MENU_main_G = 1;
    final int MENU_main_G_1 = 10;
    final int MENU_main_G_2 = 11;
    final int MENU_main_G_3 = 12;
    final int MENU_main_G_4 = 13;
    final int MENU_main_G_5 = 14;
    final int MENU_main_G_6 = 15;

    double value_c = 6;
    double value_k1 = 1;
    double value_k2 = 1;
    double value_density = 1;

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
    final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        Button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        Button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        Button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        Button10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);


        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);


        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        editText5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        editText7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);

        Button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button4.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button5.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button6.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button7.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button8.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button9.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button10.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button7.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        Button8.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        Button9.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        Button7.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        Button8.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        Button9.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        registerForContextMenu(textView1);
        registerForContextMenu(textView2);
        registerForContextMenu(textView3);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);


        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.textView2:
                menu.add(0, MENU_main_Q_1, 0, "кВт");
                menu.add(0, MENU_main_Q_2, 0, "мВт");
                menu.add(0, MENU_main_Q_3, 0, "Вт");
                break;
        }
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.textView1:
                menu.add(0, MENU_main_G_1, 0, "кг/ч");
                menu.add(0, MENU_main_G_2, 0, "м3/ч");
                menu.add(0, MENU_main_G_3, 0, "л/c");
                menu.add(0, MENU_main_G_4, 0, "кг/с");
                menu.add(0, MENU_main_G_5, 0, "м3/с");
                menu.add(0, MENU_main_G_6, 0, "фут3/нед");
                break;


        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case MENU_main_Q_1:

                textView2.setText("кВт");
                value_k1 = 1;

                break;
            case MENU_main_Q_2:

                textView2.setText("мВт");
                value_k1 = 1000;


                break;
            case MENU_main_Q_3:

                textView2.setText("Вт");
                value_k1 = 0.001;

                break;
            case MENU_main_G_1:

                textView1.setText("кг/ч");
                value_k2 = 1;


                break;
            case MENU_main_G_2:

                textView1.setText("м3/ч");
                value_k2 = value_density;


                break;
            case MENU_main_G_3:

                textView1.setText("л/с");
                value_k2 = value_density * 0.001 / 3600;

                break;
            case MENU_main_G_4:

                textView1.setText("кг/с");
                value_k2 = 1 / 3600;

                break;
            case MENU_main_G_5:

                textView1.setText("м3/с");
                value_k2 = 1 / 3600 * value_density;

                break;
            case MENU_main_G_6:

                textView1.setText("фут3/нед");

                break;
        }


        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        double value_Q = 0;
        double value_G = 0;
        double value_tdiff = 0;
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                value_c = 4.187;
                value_density = 1000;
                Button1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                Button2.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                Button6.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                               break;
            case R.id.button2:
                value_c = 1.005;
                value_density = 1.2;
                Button2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                Button1.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                Button6.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

                break;
            case R.id.button6:
                value_c = 3.8;
                value_density = 1113;
                Button6.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                Button1.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                Button2.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                                break;
            case R.id.button3:

                Button3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                Button4.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                Button5.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editText2.getText().toString())
                        || TextUtils.isEmpty(editText3.getText().toString())) {

                    return;
                }

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "рассчитывается мощность", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();


                value_G = Float.parseFloat(editText2.getText().toString());
                value_tdiff = Float.parseFloat(editText3.getText().toString());

                value_Q = value_G * value_tdiff * value_k2 * value_c / (3600 * value_k1);
                editText1.setText(String.format( Locale.US,"%.3f", value_Q ) + " " );


                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                Button3.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                Button4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                Button5.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editText1.getText().toString())
                        || TextUtils.isEmpty(editText3.getText().toString())) {

                    return;
                }

                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "рассчитывается расход", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast1.show();

                value_Q = Float.parseFloat(editText1.getText().toString());
                value_tdiff = Float.parseFloat(editText3.getText().toString());
                value_G = value_Q * value_k1 * 3600 / (value_tdiff * value_c * value_k2);

                editText2.setText(String.format( Locale.US,"%.3f", value_G ) + " " );
                break;
            case R.id.button5:
                Button3.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                Button4.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                Button5.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editText1.getText().toString())
                        || TextUtils.isEmpty(editText2.getText().toString())) {

                    return;
                }

                Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "рассчитывается разность температур", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast2.show();


                value_Q = Float.parseFloat(editText1.getText().toString());
                value_G = Float.parseFloat(editText2.getText().toString());
                value_tdiff = value_Q * value_k1 * 3600 / (value_G * value_k2 * value_c);

                editText3.setText(String.format( Locale.US,"%.3f", value_tdiff ) + " " );


                break;

            case R.id.button7:
                /*Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);*/
                break;

            case R.id.button8:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                break;

            case R.id.button9:
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent3);
                break;
```

from this point database is being using

```
            case R.id.button10:
                DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
                SQLiteDatabase db;

                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                String temperature = editText5.getText().toString();
                String percent = editText7.getText().toString();

                if (temperature.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    break;
                }
                if (percent.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    break;

                }
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DB search");

                Cursor c1 = db.query("mytable", null, "temperature , percent = ? , ?", new String[]{temperature, percent}, null, null, null);

                if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
                    int ckoef = c1.getColumnIndex("ckoef");
                    int density = c1.getColumnIndex("density");
                    do {
                        textView9.setText(c1.getString(ckoef));
                        textView11.setText(c1.getString(density));
                    } while (c1.moveToNext());

                } else
                    textView9.setText("oops");
                textView11.setText("no matches");
                c1.close();
                dbHelper.close();
                break;

        }

        }

    class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


        public DBHelper(Context context) {

            super(context, "myDB", null, DB_VERSION);

        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            int percent[] = {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30,
                    40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50};
            int temperature[] = {0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100,
                    0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100};
            double ckoef [] = {4.025, 4.034, 4.043, 4.057, 4.075, 4.085, 4.094, 4.103, 4.113, 4.122, 4.132, 3.87, 3.885, 3.9, 3.915, 3.93, 3.945, 3.96, 3.975, 3.99, 4.005, 4.02,
                    3.966, 3.977, 3.988, 3.999, 4.010, 4.022, 4.034, 4.046, 4.058, 4.069, 4.081, 3.436, 3.46, 3.5, 3.53, 3.56, 3.595, 3.62, 3.65, 3.68, 3.715, 3.74, 3.21, 3.25, 3.28, 3.32, 3.36, 3.399, 3.433, 3.472, 3.511, 3.546, 3.850 };
            double density [] = {1012.5, 1012.5, 1012.5, 1012.5, 1012.5, 1012.5, 1012.5, 1012.5, 1012.5, 1012.5, 1012.5, 1036, 1033, 1030, 1026, 1022, 1018, 1014, 1010, 1006, 1001.5, 997, 1027.852, 1025.148, 1018.85, 1015.23, 1011.63, 1008, 1004.37, 1000.741, 996.61, 992.482, 1072.667, 1068.333, 1064, 1058.167, 1052.167, 1046.667, 1041, 1035.333, 1029.667, 1023.5, 1017.333, 1089.852, 1084.926, 1080, 1073.57, 1067.148, 1061.185, 1055.222, 1049.259, 1043.296, 1036.833, 1030.37};


            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- onCreate database ---");
            // создаем таблицу с полями
            db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
                    + "id integer primary key autoincrement," + "percent integer,"
                    + "temperature integer," + "ckoef double" + "density double" + ");");
            // проверка существования записей
            Cursor c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);

                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                // заполним таблицу
                for (int i = 0; i < 55; i++) {
                    cv.put("percent", percent[i]);
                    cv.put("temperature", temperature[i]);
                    cv.put("ckoef", ckoef[i]);
                    cv.put("density", density[i]);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "id = " + db.insert("mytable", null, cv));

            }

            db.close();

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "все данные");
            c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
            c.close();

        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            if (oldVersion == 1 && newVersion == 2) {

                db.delete("mytable", null, null);

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- onUpgrade database ---");

                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

                // данные для таблицы должностей
                int percent[] = {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30,
                        40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50};
                int temperature[] = {0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100,
                        0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100};
                double ckoef [] = {4.025, 4.034, 4.043, 4.057, 4.075, 4.085, 4.094, 4.103, 4.113, 4.122, 4.132, 3.87, 3.885, 3.9, 3.915, 3.93, 3.945, 3.96, 3.975, 3.99, 4.005, 4.02,
                        3.966, 3.977, 3.988, 3.999, 4.010, 4.022, 4.034, 4.046, 4.058, 4.069, 4.081, 3.436, 3.46, 3.5, 3.53, 3.56, 3.595, 3.62, 3.65, 3.68, 3.715, 3.74, 3.21, 3.25, 3.28,
                        3.32, 3.36, 3.399, 3.433, 3.472, 3.511, 3.546, 3.850 };
                double density [] = {1012.5, 1012.5, 1012.5, 1012.5, 1012.5, 1012.5, 1012.5, 1012.5, 1012.5, 1012.5, 1012.5, 1036, 1033, 1030, 1026, 1022, 1018, 1014, 1010, 1006, 1001.5,
                        997, 1027.852, 1025.148, 1018.85, 1015.23, 1011.63, 1008,
                        1004.37, 1000.741, 996.61, 992.482, 1072.667, 1068.333, 1064, 1058.167, 1052.167, 1046.667, 1041, 1035.333, 1029.667, 1023.5, 1017.333, 1089.852, 1084.926, 1080,
                        1073.57, 1067.148, 1061.185, 1055.222, 1049.259, 1043.296, 1036.833, 1030.37};

                db.beginTransaction();
                try {
                    // создаем таблицу должностей
                    db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
                            + "id integer primary key autoincrement," + "percent integer,"
                            + "temperature integer," + "ckoef double" + "density double" + ");");

                    // заполняем ее
                    for (int i = 0; i < 55; i++) {
                        cv.put("percent", percent[i]);
                        cv.put("temperature", temperature[i]);
                        cv.put("ckoef", ckoef[i]);
                        cv.put("density", density[i]);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "id = " + db.insert("mytable", null, cv));
                    }


                    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                } finally {
                    db.endTransaction();
                }


            }
        }
    }

}
```

Error Log:

```
11-17 06:48:17.345 1024-1024/com.example.prog E/SQLiteLog: (1) table mytable has no column named density 
11-17 06:48:17.371 1024-1024/com.example.prog E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting temperature=0 ckoef=4.025 density=1012.5 percent=10 
11-17 06:48:17.371 1024-1024/com.example.prog E/SQLiteDatabase: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table mytable has no column named density (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO mytable(temperature,ckoef,density,percent) VALUES (?,?,?,?) 
11-17 06:48:17.371 1024-1024/com.example.prog E/SQLiteDatabase: at
```

please help, attention to button10 and following code

Comment: 11-17 06:48:17.345 1024-1024/com.example.prog E/SQLiteLog: (1) table mytable has no column named density
11-17 06:48:17.371 1024-1024/com.example.prog E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting temperature=0 ckoef=4.025 density=1012.5 percent=10
11-17 06:48:17.371 1024-1024/com.example.prog E/SQLiteDatabase: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table mytable has no column named density (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO mytable(temperature,ckoef,density,percent) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
11-17 06:48:17.371 1024-1024/com.example.prog E/SQLiteDatabase:     at

Comment: etc with each temperature (1-100, with a step by 10 degrees) and temperature

Comment: and percent, temperature and percent

Comment: said, thankyou so much, i missed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to put "**,**" between two column`(ckoef and density)` in create table statement.

```
  db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
                    + "id integer primary key autoincrement," + "percent integer,"
                    + "temperature integer," + "ckoef double," + "density double" + ");");
```